# Loop through a hash member in order

Tags: perl, oop, hash

how can i have a hash member of a class ordered? My class looks like this

```
    package TestSuiteInterface {

    use Tie::IxHash;

    sub new {
        my ($class, $name) = @_;
        my $self = {};
        my %schedulerdata = {};
        tie(%schedulerdata, 'Tie::IxHash');
        $self->{name} = $name;
        $self->{scheduler} = %schedulerdata;
        bless $self, $class;
        return $self;                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    }
    sub getVariables {
        my ($self) = shift;
        return $self->{variables}
    }
    sub loadtests {
        my ($self) = shift;
        {
            #tie(my %data, 'Tie::IxHash');                                                                                                                                                                                                   
            #%data = %{$self->{scheduler}};                                                                                                                                                                                                  
            my @scheduler = values %{$self->{scheduler}};
            #die "oops" unless $self->{scheduler}                                                                                                                                                                                            
            $_->() for (@scheduler);
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Above i try to use Tie::IxHash. i try to figure out how i could do that for a $self->{scheduler} which later a subclass will add items. for example

```
package Test {
    use base 'TestSuiteInterface';
    use main_common;
    sub new {
        my ($class, $name) = @_;
        my $self = {};
        class->SUPER::new($name);
        $self->{variables}={};
        $self->{scheduler} = {
            boot_linuxrc => sub{ loadtest("boot/boot_linuxrc"); },
            first_boot => sub{ loadtest("installation/first_boot");}
        };
        bless $self, $class;
        return $self;
    }
}
```

To use the Tie::IxHash i have to use it before the variable is set, right? So to use it in loadtests is not useful at the end. Can i do it in the constructor or how else can i take back the $self->{scheduler} in order inside a loop?

Answer (score 4):

In your `new()` method, you create a Tie::IxHash object and store it inside your test object.

```
my %schedulerdata = {};
tie(%schedulerdata, 'Tie::IxHash');
...
$self->{scheduler} = %schedulerdata;
```

Actually, there are a couple of small errors there. Firstly, you initialise your hash with a hash reference.

```
my %schedulerdata = {};
```

Really, you want to initialise it with an empty list:

```
my %schedulerdata = ();
```

Or, better, just rely on Perl to initialise it as an empty hash.

```
my %schedulerdata;
```

And, secondly, you try to store the hash in your object. But object attributes can only be scalars, so you need to store a reference to the hash in your object.

```
$self->{scheduler} = \%schedulerdata;
```

Putting all that together, your constructor method should look like this:

```
sub new {
    my ($class, $name) = @_;
    my $self = {};
    my %schedulerdata;
    tie(%schedulerdata, 'Tie::IxHash');
    $self->{name} = $name;
    $self->{scheduler} = \%schedulerdata;
    bless $self, $class;
    return $self;
}
```

But those problems aren't what's causing this not to work. That comes a bit later - when you're giving values to your scheduler. Your code looks like this:

```
$self->{scheduler} = {
    boot_linuxrc => sub{ loadtest("boot/boot_linuxrc"); },
    first_boot   => sub{ loadtest("installation/first_boot"); }
};
```

But think about what this is doing. You're creating a brand new anonymous hash and storing a reference to that hash in your object. That will overwrite your carefully constructed tied hash and replace it with a standard (non-tied) hash.

In order to retain the tied nature of your hash, you need to add key/values pairs to it - not overwrite it completely. I think that code like this will work.

```
$self->{scheduler}->{boot_linuxrc} = sub{ loadtest("boot/boot_linuxrc"); };
$self->{scheduler}->{first_boot}   = sub{ loadtest("installation/first_boot"); };
```

**Note:** If your code included `use warnings` (and Perl code should always include `use warnings`) then the line:

```
my %schedulerdata = {};
```

would have triggered a warning:

> Reference found where even-sized list expected

Which is why we always recommend including `use warnings` :-)

Comment: I had noticed the first part and i worked around it. But pretty much, my understanding is that there is not way to "tie" the $self->{scheduler} itself, somehow, right?

Comment: @b10n1k: That's right. `$self->{scheduler}` is a slot for storing data. And you can't tie that slot, you can only tie the data that is stored in the slot. You can store a reference to a tied hash there. But you can't later overwrite that hash and expected the "tied-ness" to stick.

Answer (score 1):

My solution, at the end, was to go without the *Tie::IxHash*. Instead I used a separate function to get an ordered list and assign it to the instance members. I will post it as another way, as the solution from @Dave Cross is still correct.

```
sub set_scheduler {    
￼        my ($self, @list) = @_;
￼        # get a list of the subroutines of the hash
￼        my @order    = map { $list[($_ * 2) + 1] } 0 .. (@list / 2) - 1;
￼        my %schedule = @list;
￼        $self->{scheduler}       = \%schedule;
￼        $self->{scheduler_order} = \@order;
￼        return $self;
￼    }
```

The @list now contains 4 elements. [boot_linuxrc, sub{ loadtest("boot/boot_linuxrc")}, first_boot, sub{ loadtest("installation/first_boot")}]. The set_scheduler uses map to give me a list of the subs using the indexes of [1] and [3] of the @list in the example. *0 .. (@list / 2) - 1* is to get just the correct size (2 items) in the @order.

I replace the previous *$self->{scheduler}* in the *package Test* with the code bellow which uses an array of the items

```
$self->set_scheduler(
            boot_linuxrc       => sub { loadtest("boot/boot_linuxrc") },
            installer_extended => sub { loadtest("installation/first_boot") }
        );
```

Then I run the following in the loadtests

```
$_->() for (@{$self->{scheduler_order}});
```

Thanks @DaveCross